# Is my .git file safe? too many active changes problem

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I unziped a file containing approximately 7k files on my project folder by mistake.

While the files were being extracted, I noticed that Visual Studio Code showed this message:

> The git repository at [...] has too many active changes, only a subset
> of Git features will be enabled.

When the extraction was completed, I moved the newly generated folder to a different location outside de repository.

Is my git repository somehow corrupted now? Or I can safely continue working as before as if nothing had happened?

Both Visual Studio Code and GitKraken show me the same unstaged files that I had before the *faux pas*, but I'm not sure if I have to do some checks before commiting (is a local repo).

Comment: If I understand correctly you change the directory location to not be in your project and you want that, Git is like a tree and it is starting at the top of the directory that you started with `git init` and contain all of the sub directories, moving files and directories from that tree wouldn't effect the project you should just check with `git status` after removing/changing the sub_directory you want and then add a new commit after that it's like that file/directory never have existed before, but be careful that the sub_directory doesn't contain dependencies of your main project

Comment: If you didn't `commit` those changes , you are safe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't stage the unzipped files and simply did some file operations in the directory without actively using git (stage/add, commit), you should be fine.

You can confirm this if the status of you repo is normal after a commit: `nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Answer (score 4):

> When the extraction was completed, I moved the newly generated folder to a different location outside de repository.

Then simply close and relaunch VSCode.
As seen in [`microsoft/vscode` issue 96577](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96577#issuecomment-621880708), that will force a status refresh, and the warning should be gone.

But the git repository itself has not been "corrupted" by this episode. This message comes only from VSCode Git integration itself.

Comment: This answer explains everything that happened precisely. IMO this should be the accepted answer.